# CP search for entries where a specific field is empty

Tags: entries, control-panel, search

In the control panel, is it possible to search for entries where a specific field is empty? The Craft [search syntax page](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching#supported-syntaxes) doesn't help here, and the logical values used in twig don't seem to work here. I haven't been able to find any other info about this either.

*Side note: the search syntax is a bit out of reach for many non-dev users (read clients). An advanced search/filter form for entries would be awesome.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to search for every `body` field that did *not* have a value, the syntax would be:

```
-body:*
```

Which basically says, give me every `body` field that has a value and negates it.  Have updated the [search docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching#supported-syntaxes) with an example.

Comment: I just noticed that the above example wont work if fuzzy search is enabled (so where "subRight" and/or "subLeft" settings are true).

Comment: Ahh... yeah, good catch.  Not sure if I've got a solution for that one at the moment.

Comment: This works with subRight/subLeft set to true as of Craft 3 RC5.

Answer (score 1):

We use Zenbu for this exact thing. As we're importing a lot of data, we need to find which entries are missing data - https://zenbustudio.com/software/zenbu-craftcms